# (Python) ELSE is being executed even when IF has been satisfied?

Tags: python, boolean

Doing my homework rn and a bit stuck, why does the code execute "else" even thought the "if" has been satisfied? Ignore the sloppy code, I'm very new :/

```
order1 = input("What would you like to order?: \n \n" + "1: " + orderBurger + "\n" + "2: " + orderFries + "\n" + "3: " + orderDrink + "\n" + "\nAnswer = ")

while order == True:
 if order1 == 1:
  print("You have selected to order 1: " + orderBurger)
 elif order1 == 2:
  print("You have selected to order 1: " + orderFries)
 elif order1 == 3:
  print("You have selected to order 1: " + orderDrink)
 else:
  print("Invalid Input")
 check = input("Is this your final item?:" + "1: " + q1 + "2: " + q2  + "Answer = ")
 if check == 1:
  print("Your items have been added to the basket")
  break
 elif check == 2:
  check
 elif check == 3:
  check
 else:
  print("Invalid input")
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkem.png)

Comment: Please edit the output __as text__ into your question

Comment: `input` in python 3.x returns a string. So when you're comparing `order1 == 1` you're basically comparing `'1' == 1` whichs is `False`.

Comment: You need to do `order1 = int(order1)` before the while loop.

Comment: `order1` is a `str`, so none of your comparisons will ever be true.

Comment: Also, use 4 spaces for indentation, as your code will be *much* easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `type(order1)`, you'll see if your answer is a string or an int. If it's a string (and I think it is), you can convert it into int using `int(order1)`, or replace your code by `if order1 == '1'`

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is very important in Python. Based on how the indentations are implemented, the code blocks for conditions get executed.

A misplaced indent can lead to unexpected execution of a code block.

**Here is a working demo of the ordering program**

```
# File name:  order-demo.py

moreItems = True
while (moreItems == True):
    order = input("\n What would you like to order?\n" 
                  + " 1: Burger\n 2: Fries\n 3: Drink\n Answer = ")

    if ((order == "1") or (order == "2") or (order == "3")):
        print("You have selected to order " + order)
        print("Your item has been added to the basket.\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")

    check = input("Is this your final item?: \n 1: Yes \n 2: No \n Answer = ")
    if check == "1":
            print("\n Thank you. Please proceed to checkout.")
            moreItems = False       
    elif check == "2":
            print("Please continue your shopping")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 order-demo.py 

 What would you like to order?
 1: Burger
 2: Fries
 3: Drink
 Answer = 1
You have selected to order 1
Your item has been added to the basket.

Is this your final item?: 
 1: Yes 
 2: No 
 Answer = 2
Please continue your shopping

 What would you like to order?
 1: Burger
 2: Fries
 3: Drink
 Answer = 2
You have selected to order 2
Your item has been added to the basket.

Is this your final item?: 
 1: Yes 
 2: No 
 Answer = 1

 Thank you. Please proceed to checkout.
$
```

Answer (score 0):

replace first line with this :

```
order1 = int( input("What would you like to order?: \n \n" + "1: " + orderBurger + "\n" + "2: " + orderFries + "\n" + "3: " + orderDrink + "\n" + "\nAnswer = ") )
```